# matplotlib trisurf slow while moving graph

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, data-visualization

totally 4186 data points.

here's my computer configure. moving graph is very slow. any faster way to plot surface chart with matrix like data? thanks.

and  my computer is not that bad. disk is samsung SSD EVO 840 500g

[image]

[image]

with mayavi2 surf plot as suggested by mrcl and my code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_csv('result.csv')
import numpy as np
from mayavi import mlab
x,y,z = a.fast.values, a.slow.values, a.profit.values
mlab.points3d(x,y,z)
mlab.show()
```

[image]

Comment: matplotlib can be very slow for 3D plotting. You should try to use mayavi. Here is a link with a bunch of examples. http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/examples.html

Comment: tried, don't know how to get use standalone program of mayavi2, instead of scripting. it seems to me it only takes vtk format not csv. and i have no knowledge of VTK.

Comment: I don't know think you can load a csv file on the stand alone interface! I think you must load your data in a numpy array and plot your data using the surf command. I will give you an example.

Comment: Thanks, I tried, here's what I got by using the same data with surf:(

Answer (score 1):

An example of how to use the surf plotting in mayavi.

```
import numpy
from mayavi.mlab import *

def f(x, y):
    sin, cos = numpy.sin, numpy.cos
    return sin(x + y) + sin(2 * x - y) + cos(3 * x + 4 * y)

x, y = numpy.mgrid[-7.:7.05:0.1, -5.:5.05:0.05]
s = surf(x, y, f(x,y))
#cs = contour_surf(x, y, f, contour_z=0)
show()
```

Cheers

Comment: Thank you but what if z is not a function, all 3 dimensions are data points?

Comment: In this case you can use http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/mlab_helper_functions.html#triangular-mesh. But that can be a little bi trickier. I can't have a look on that now. Hope it gives some directions.